# Invalid use of void expression when casting a void* buffer

Tags: c, casting, compiler-errors, void, void-pointers

My function takes a void* buffer and must fill it with what's inside my char* buffer_rep. But when I write this:

```
int function(void *buffer, int size)
{
   char buffer_rep[512];
   // my buffer_rep is filled up with the call of another function.
   // It is not empty
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {   // size is below 512
       buffer[i] = buffer_rep[i]; 
   }
return 0;
}
```

The line inside the for expression gives me the error "Invalid use of void expression". If I try to cast the buffer like this:

```
(char *)buffer[i] = buffer_rep[i];
```

I get the same error with a warning "Invalid type conversion". I also tried with (char) instead of (char *).
I don't have much experience in C and I tried searching for a solution on my own, but usually people don't get this error while casting. I assume there's something obvious I don't see.

Comment: `((char *)buffer)[i] = buffer_rep[i];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* cast the pointer, but the problem with your cast is that you cast the *element* and not the pointer. I.e. the expression `(char *)buffer[i]` is equal to `(char *)(buffer[i])`.

If you use parentheses at the correct places it should be alright: `((char *)buffer)[i]`

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply the cast to `buffer` and not to `buffer[i]`.

Change your code to

```
((char *)buffer) [i] = buffer_rep[i];
```